# Windows lock the session after few seconds when using Skype

Tags: windows-10, skype

Every time I start a Skype call, if I'm inactive (doesn't move the mouse or type on the keyboard) for ~10sec, my screen goes black and my session locked and I need to retype my password.

This happens only when I'm on a call Skype. I tried to be inactive for several minutes without being in a call Skype and the session won't lock.

My power strategy is to goes in sleep mode after 30 minutes of inactivity. I'm not in power safe mode.

-- I'm on a Windows 10 computer running Skype 7.39.0.102

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Many thank's !